# Stable Baselines 3 DQN Model refuses to use CUDA even though it recognizes my GPU

Tags: tensorflow, stable-baselines

as the title states. My DQN Model refuses to use the GPU for a custom environment with Stable Baselines 3.

```
model = DQN("MlpPolicy", env, device="cuda")
```

- My GPU is an RTX 2070 Super
- Installed CUDA Version is 10.1
- Installed cudNN Version is 7.5.0 (for 10.1)
- Installed Tensorflow Version is 2.2

CUDA works when I use tensorflow for machine learning on its own but seems to not work with Stable Baselines 3. It always defaults back to CPU but when I let it print my available CUDA devices right before creating the model it shows that there is one available, which refers to my RTX 2070 Super

All plugins are loaded properly when tensorflow initializes and there are no errors.

Unfortunately I am unable to find anything regarding this issue.

I have tried a multitude of different CUDA Versions along with changing my tensorflow versions and installing the specific tensorflow-gpu package but nothing has changed.

here is the log when running my code

```
2023-02-01 16:28:20.409397: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.691033: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.713878: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:2d:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.815GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2023-02-01 16:28:21.714097: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Num GPUs Available:  1
Using cpu device
Wrapping the env with a `Monitor` wrapper
Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.
2023-02-01 16:28:21.717235: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.719513: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.720370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.723773: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.725979: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.732353: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2023-02-01 16:28:21.732490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that the GPU is not being used?

Comment: Usage is always at 0% and when my model starts learning it says "using cpu device"

Comment: can you report the *precise log* of your script? Also the version of Stable-baseline3

Comment: I added it to the post. My sbl3 version is 1.7.0

Comment: stable-baselines3 uses pytorch as a backend. What does `torch.cuda.is_available()` return?

Comment: These are just (I) informational messages and also GPU is initialized. Please provide standalone code to understand and replicate the issue.